# Laravel Callback Function Controller not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a route and a controller function to process the notification which is being posted from an external payment gateway. I'm using Guzzle to process the raw output.

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get('php://input');
$content = (string) $res->getBody();
$notification = json_decode($content);

// add to database
```

I am suspecting I am unable to do this in Laravel but I could not find a solution. I did a post test on https://www.apirequest.io/ but I got this error:

> Error: Request has been terminated Possible causes: the network is
>   offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the
>   page is being unloaded, etc.

Any help is appreciated!

I tried without using Guzzle as well

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$notification = json_decode($data);
```

I tried running a blank function to write into a database, that did not work therefore I think I'm doing it wrongly in Laravel.

Comment: there is nothing to process. Just feed $data into json_decode

Comment: i tried json_decode($data) as well without Guzzle

Comment: what payment gateway? Did you try to log what gateway is sending you? - Please attache the sample of data gateway is sending you. Do not try to simulate gateway until you realy know format of the data it sends

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're depending on Guzzle? Why not simply inject the `Request` object to your Controller function and get the body content from there?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function storePaymentNotification(Request $request)
    {
       // Raw content string
        $content = $request->getContent();

       // JSON decoded data
       $json = $request->json();
    }

    ...
}
```